# Using wrapfigure with custom paragraph breaks

Tags: floats, paragraphs, wrapfigure, parskip

In my document, I've modified `\parskip` to give a nice break between paragraphs. But this means that `\wrapfigure` calculates the number of lines wrong, and gives itself a significantly larger margin than it needs.

How can I fix this? I'd like the text to flow in right underneath the `\wrapfigure`, the way it does if I remove the `\parskip` adjustment.

MWE:

[image: this is wrong]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{wrapfigure}

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

[image]

You can specify the multiple of lines that should be short:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlength{\parskip}{1em}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}[9]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
\lipsum[2]
\end{wrapfigure}

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

Short paragraph

\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This seems like it solves the problem nicely, but I'm confused as to how to find that `9` you used. If I don't know in advance how the paragraphs are going to flow or how many breaks there'll be, is there a way I can have TeX calculate this?

Comment: It is worth a note that the the optional added here _`[9]`_ is controlling the narrow lines below the figure. You can read more about it if you run `texdoc wrapfig` in your terminal/command line (or read it online [here](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/wrapfig/wrapfig-doc.pdf))

Comment: I get your output with the new lipsum package even without your addition, only in texlive 2017 it changes something.